# Why and how the new keyword is being used with the already existing object of a class?

Tags: php, class, object, new-operator

I'm using **PHP 7.1.11**

Consider below code :

```
<?php
  class Test {
    static public function getNew() {
      return new static;
    }
  }

  class Child extends Test {}

  $obj1 = new Test();
  $obj2 = new $obj1;
?>
```

Above code snippet has been taken from the **PHP Manual**.

From the above code I'm not able to understand why and how the *new keyword* is being used with the existing object of a `class Test`?

What's the intention behind doing like this?

Is this kind of usage of *new keyword* recommended?

If you really want to assign an already existing object of a class to some variable then can't it be done by simply writing the statement `$obj2 = $obj1;`?

What's the difference between below two statements? Which one is better and should be preferred?

```
$obj2 = new $obj1;
$obj2 = $obj1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$obj2 = new $obj1;` (creates a new instance of an object of the same class as $obj1) !== `$obj2 = $obj1;` (which creates `$obj2` a reference to $obj1) !== `$obj2 = clone $obj1;` (which creates a new $obj2 with all the same property values as the original but as a new object instance)

For the 3 different cases that I cited in my comments above, let's create a simple class and instantiate it:

```
class User {
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;

    public function __construct($firstname = 'TEST', $lastname = 'USER') {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
        $this->lastname = $lastname;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return implode(' ', [$this->firstname, $this->lastname]);
    }
}

// original instance of a User
$obj1 = new User('Mark', 'Baker');
var_dump($obj1->getName());    // Mark Baker
```

---

Now if we simply assign a new variable to the original, we're setting a pointer to the original (because it's an object), similar to a reference

```
// Simply set reference to our original User
$obj2 = $obj1;
var_dump($obj2->getName());    // Mark Baker

// And if we change properties of the instance, it changes for both because it's a reference
$obj2->firstname = 'David Mark';
var_dump($obj2->getName());    // David Mark Baker
var_dump($obj1->getName());    // David Mark Baker
```

Any changes to either will be reflected in the other, because they are pointing to the same object instance

---

If we use `clone`, then we're creating a brand new object instance, but already populated with the property values from the original

```
// Clone the original object, this will create a new instance but will inherit property values of the original
$obj3 = clone $obj1;
var_dump($obj3->getName());    // David Mark Baker

// But changing properties of the clone won't affect the original in any way
$obj3->firstname = 'Mark';
var_dump($obj3->getName());    // Mark Baker
var_dump($obj1->getName());    // David Mark Baker
```

Now if we change properties of the original, it won't affect the clone (or vice versa) because they are unique instances.

---

The we have the third case, where we're using `new` with an instance rather than  class name.

```
// Now create a new instance of the same type of object as your original User
// If we had mandatory constructor arguments, then we'd have to provide them $obj4 = new $obj1('a', 'b');
// But because they're optional, we  can get away with allowing the defaults

$obj4 = new $obj1;
var_dump($obj4->getName());    // TEST USER
```

If we didn't know what class type `$obj1` was, then it doesn't matter (though it would have been easy enough to find out). This creates a brand new instance of whatever class `$obj1` was, without the property inheritance that `clone` gives, nor is it  reference like `$obj2 = $obj1` gave..... it still calls the constructor, so we have to pass any mandatory constructor arguments (or get an error).

Answer (score 3):

The `new` operator always creates a new instance of an object. It takes one argument, which can be a hard-coded class name:

```
$newObject = new MyClass();
```

Or a variable that contains a class name:

```
$className = 'MyClass';
$newObject = new $className();
```

Or an existing instance of an object of the type you want to create:

```
$oldObject = new MyClass();
$newObject = new $oldObject(); // Same as using "new MyClass();"
```

You'll probably never use the third case.

Comment: Just clear a small doubt I have. In your answer everywhere you have used the term 'instance of an object' but actually 'object itself is an instance of a class'. Then how can you make/say 'instance of an object(which is already an instance of a class)'?

Comment: Semantics. Replace "instance of an object" with "an instantiated object" if it helps.